# How can I make dmg file for OSX from a IntelliJ-maven project?

Tags: java, macos, maven, dmg, qupath

I'm new in IntelliJ-maven-java programming, and I want to make dmg file for Mac OS as a result of my program.

My development environment is Ubuntu-IntelliJ-Java-Maven. As I searched, there are some plugins that are able to make dmg file from intelliJ, but it is actually very complicated to me.

Could you tell me the order of the process kindly? 
 Thanks in advance.

Futhermore, following messages are from command when I run `mvn install`with `appbundle-maven-plugin` from https://github.com/federkasten/appbundle-maven-plugin.
 If I did something stupid, could you tell me which part is awkward?

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.623 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-26T14:16:36+09:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/240M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal sh.tak.appbundler:appbundle-maven-
plugin:1.2.0:bundle (default) on project qupath: Execution default of goal sh.tak.appbundler:appbundle-maven-plugin:1.2.0:bundle failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]
```

and this is my maven-plugin code.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>sh.tak.appbundler</groupId>
        <artifactId>appbundle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>src.main.java.qupath.QuPath</mainClass>
                <jrePath>/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre</jrePath>
                <generateDiskImageFile>true</generateDiskImageFile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bundle</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828620/create-mac-dmg-file-from-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build a dmg Mac OS X file (on a non-Mac platform)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286419/how-to-build-a-dmg-mac-os-x-file-on-a-non-mac-platform)

Answer (score 0):

Use Java packager https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html  as per this tutorial http://centerkey.com/mac/java.

Comment: These are instructions for a Mac. The OP is using Ubuntu